# What function removes apostrophes when making a slug?

Tags: slug, sanitization

I am trying to convert a post title to a slug.  I used `sanitize_title_with_dashes`, thinking that's what WordPress uses.  However, if my post title has an apostrophe in it, `sanitize_title_with_dashes` does not strip out the apostrophe.  Instead, it escapes the apostrophe with a backslash.

For example, if I use the default post editor to create a post named "Bob's Boutique", WordPress core will correctly create the slug as "bobs-boutique".

If I try to convert "Bob's Boutqiue" to a post slug using `sanitize_title_with_dashes` in functions.php, the result is "bob\'s-boutique".

Is there an additional function that WordPress uses when making slugs that strips out apostrophes?

Comment: `echo sanitize_title_with_dashes("Bob's Boutqiue")` outputs `bobs-boutique`, I don't get an escaped quote.

Comment: sanitize_title_with_dashes should work, so we need to see more code to know why the value is being escaped - perhaps you are also wrapping it in a WordPress esc_html or another function.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function to remove the apostrophe:

```
preg_replace( "/[:’]/", "", $title );
```

Comment: Really? Add it where exactly? Can we just drop that in `functions.php` and BAM! It works?

Comment: What @s_ha_dum means is that this is not gonna work.. the very least it requires is to inside a function, allowing the $title to be passed to it..